# How to install Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics, ati

Been trying to install Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620 in a new install of UBUNTU 11.10 x86_64, but I haven't got any idea of how to accomplish this.

I had it installed before, and working, but now I can't.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Actually the default xorg drivers are Gallium's. If one types: `glxinfo`at the terminhal you are greeted with the info that mesa-utils are not installed. If one installs mesa-utils typing `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`at the terminal and retyping  `glxinfo | grep -i gallium`at the terminal one gets the correct info.

The same info can also be obtained from the system info GUI after doing the outlined above.

Greetings from this 'Tumbleweed'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing it up, it comes preinstalled, although not visible.

To make it visible it suffices to run `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` in a terminal and checking the system info GUI again.

Thanks